# Azure DevOps Pipeline Resource Trigger is no longer working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have a deployment pipeline that should run when the build pipeline completes. Here's the yaml:

```yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: BuildPipeline 
    source: buildpipelinename
    trigger: true
```

I have set the `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds` for both the source (build) and triggered (deploy) pipelines to the correct branch, and the build pipeline creates an artifact. If I run the deployment pipeline manually, the latest build artifacts download as expected - the problem is only the trigger. This used to work and I don't know what changed. I have reverted my changes to the entire file since the last successful automatic deployment and deleted all other branches from my repo with no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft addressed this bug with [this fix](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Some-recent-issues-detected-related-to-p/1620293)

Answer (score 0):

Tested here on a new project with pipeline1 and pipeline2. Pipeline2 successfully triggered when pipeline1 completes.

Possibly a bug with your project/azure devops. Try renaming the source pipeline and updating the trigger to the new value and see if that helps.

```
#pipeline2.yml
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pipeline1
      source: pipeline1
      trigger: true
```